# Keepalive SFTP connection in Control-M Advanced File Transfer

Tags: control-m

I have a requirement to send a 10 GB file to a client SFTP server through an automated process. We are using BMC Control-M to automate the whole process.

However, the client SFTP Server disconnects the session after 300 seconds due to inactivity. And since the file size is quite big, file transfer fails due to SFTP Server disconnect.

During testing, I was sending the file manually, through WinSCP. In WinSCP, we have an option called Keepalives, that will keep a FTP connection alive.

Is there any similar option we can set in Control-M AFT settings?

Answer (score 0):

This can be changed by right clicking on the "Control-M for Advanced File Transfer" (or "Control-M for Managed File Transfer", depending on which version you have) in Control-M Configuration Manager (CCM).

From there, open "Configuration Management" then update "Connection timeout (seconds)" to your required value.